# MPAndroidChart: bottom x-axis and multiple y-axes

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have two questions about this awesome Android chart library:

1) I cannot find a way to put the x-axis at the bottom of the chart: is it possible?

2) is it possible to plot data against two (or more) y-axes on the same chart?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Good Question,  
How can I plot more then one points on same Y_AXIS position. I have to take dates on X-axis and on Same Date I have more than one values. How can I do this ?

Comment: Have you got any solution so far ?

Answer (score 52):

A bit has changed in the library. Now you will need to do as follows:

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

This will set the x-axis label at the bottom

Comment: this should be the correct question, this works!

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to put the `XLabels` to the bottom.

Call:

```
XLabels xl = chart.getXLabels();
xl.setPosition(XLabelPosition.BOTTOM);
```

Different y-axes descriptions (`YLabels`, with different data) are currently not supported.

Comment: Is multiple y axis supported now?

Comment: How can I plot more then one points on same Y_AXIS position. I have to take dates on X-axis and on Same Date I have more than one values. How can I do this ?